# How to select one character in a string in between characters with Regex?

Tags: regex

Given this single-line input:

> `City, Country|john.doe@example.com|john-doe-1234567|https://www.example.com/john-doe-site|john|doe|`

I want to know if this is possible to grab the last two `|` characters - ie the pipes surrounding `doe`, but without matching `doe`.

I know the regex code to get all the `|` with `(\n?)\|`.

I've tried `(?<=[a-z])\|\w+\|` and `(?<![a-z])\|\w+\|`. The positive lookbehind and negative lookbehind both were closest I got but didn't hit the mark... In VSCode, I get something like this:

[image]

Currently, can not figure out a way where I get **just the last two `|` characters** without also returning a word that comes in-between the `|`.

Comment: "how would you do that?" match all the `|`, capture the last 3 one by one. If you specify three `|` at the end of your regex, your "match all the `|`" part of the regex won't be able to match those, and will let your capturing group match and capture them (that said you "match all the `|`" regex doesn't seem correct, but i'm confident you'll find a solution by yourself)

Comment: Yeah... not really unfortunately. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: [`\|(?=(?:[^|]*\|)?[^|]*$)`](https://regex101.com/r/pCVCfD/1)

Comment: @RyszardCzech Thanks so much! I don't think I would've figured it out! I'm going to have to break it down later to learn more about it!

Answer (score 1):

Use a look ahead for the rest of input being 0-n non-pipes then an optional pipe (which includes being nothing - ie will match the last char):

```
\|(?=[^|]*\|?$)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/h8jvpmoQy5Yt12).

Regex breakdown:

- `\|` a (literal) pipe
- `(?=...)` a look ahead, which asserts that what follows matches `...`
- `[^|]*` any number (including none) of chars not a pipe (note how the pipe char doesn't need escaping when in a character class, as is the case for most chars that would otherwise have special meaning)
- `\|?` an optional pipe char
- `$` end of input

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
\|(?=(?:[^|]*\|)?[^|]*$)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/pCVCfD/1).

**BREAKDOWN**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \|                       '|'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^|]*                    any character except: '|' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \|                       '|'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^|]*                    any character except: '|' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```